# Simple loading spinner not displaying properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

It is displaying if I hover over and inspect, but it's not visible at all. The image is in the same folder. I think all the file names are correct, but I'm not really sure as to what the problem is. Please help, it's just for a basic note file.

JS:

```
const renderLoader = parent => {
    const loader =  `
        <div class="loader">
            <svg>
                <use href="32. spinner.png"></use>
            </svg>
        </div>
        `
    document.querySelector(parent).insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', loader);
}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="32. loading spinner.css">
<script src="32. loading spinner.js"></script> 

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Loading spinner Notes</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="results">
            <h1>RESULTS DIV</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="answers">
            <h1>ANSWERS DIV</h1>
        </div>
        <!-- EVERYTHING IS WORKING BUT THE SPINNER IS NOT SHOWING THE IMAGE -->
        <input value="load spinner for results" type="submit" onClick="renderLoader('.results')">
        <input value="load spinner for answers" type="submit" onClick="renderLoader('.answers')">

        <h1>Look at console</h1>
    </body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
.loader {
    margin: 5rem auto;
    text-align: center; }
    .loader svg {
      height: 5.5rem;
      width: 5.5rem;
      /* fill: #F59A83; */
      transform-origin: 44% 50%;
      animation: rotate 1.5s infinite linear; }

  @keyframes rotate {
    0% {
      transform: rotate(0); }
    100% {
      transform: rotate(360deg); } }
```

Answer (score 1):

I see your markup for the spinner are `<svg>` and `<use>` tags at the time you are trying to use .PNG file, so either use regular img tag or use the `<svg><use>` tags properly,

I think your markup should be like this:

```
<svg>
    <use xlink:href="path/to/svg/file.svg#SVG_ID"></use>
</svg>
```